# Spring boot starts with wrong version number

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm currently trying to migrate an inherited project to Spring Boot. So far i made the following changes to my pom.xml:

```
<parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <version>Angel.SR3</version>
</parent>
...
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
...
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <goals>
            <goal>repackage</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Maven seems to resolve the packages accordingly, but for some unknown reason the application launches with an older version of spring boot.

[image: Maven depencies resolution]

I tried cleaning, updating and installing Maven dependencies several times, but with no visible effect. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE 1**

Here is the output of running `mvn depndency:tree` (i left out the downloading-section for readbility):

```
[INFO] BundlerSpringMVC:BundlerSpringMVC:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- javax:javaee-web-api:jar:7.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:jar:1.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:1.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:1.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:3.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:1.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:jar:1.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka:jar:1.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-core:jar:1.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-client:jar:1.1.147:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-eventbus:jar:0.1.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.archaius:archaius-core:jar:0.6.5:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.8:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.servo:servo-core:jar:0.7.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.13:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.13:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-apache-client4:jar:1.11:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-httpclient:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-commons-util:jar:0.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- com.netflix.governator:governator:jar:1.2.10:runtime
[INFO] |  |     +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-ribbon:jar:1.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-transport:jar:2.0.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- io.reactivex:rxnetty-contexts:jar:0.4.6:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxnetty-servo:jar:0.4.6:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-core:jar:1.4.10:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxnetty:jar:0.4.6:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.0.25.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.0.25.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.0.25.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:4.0.25.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |        +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.0.25.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |        +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.0.25.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |        \- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.0.25.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-core:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-loadbalancer:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-statistics:jar:0.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxjava:jar:1.0.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-eureka:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-security:jar:1.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.4.6:compile
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.5.6-Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.5.6-Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] \- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
```

**Update 2:**

This is output from running `spring-boot:run`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building BundlerSpringMVC 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.4.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ BundlerSpringMVC >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ BundlerSpringMVC ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Raoul\workspace\BundlerSpringMVC\src\main\resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Raoul\workspace\BundlerSpringMVC\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ BundlerSpringMVC ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ BundlerSpringMVC ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Raoul\workspace\BundlerSpringMVC\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ BundlerSpringMVC ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.4.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ BundlerSpringMVC <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.4.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ BundlerSpringMVC ---
2015-08-22 10:50:54.888  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] util.EditorApplication                   : Starting EditorApplication on WIN-0A143I2P3J6 with PID 6628 (C:\Users\Raoul\workspace\BundlerSpringMVC\target\classes started by Raoul in C:\Users\Raoul\workspace\BundlerSpringMVC)
2015-08-22 10:50:54.969  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@58be3622: startup date [Sat Aug 22 10:50:54 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-08-22 10:50:55.364  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2015-08-22 10:50:55.796  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'encrypt.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.KeyProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-08-22 10:50:55.797  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'encryptionBootstrapConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$627e90e3] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-08-22 10:50:56.041  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] util.EditorApplication                   : Started EditorApplication in 2.098 seconds (JVM running for 24.015)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.4.RELEASE)

2015-08-22 10:50:57.659 ERROR 6628 --- [lication.main()] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/bootstrap/default":Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2015-08-22 10:50:57.674  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4d252d58: startup date [Sat Aug 22 10:50:57 CEST 2015]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@58be3622
2015-08-22 10:50:59.900  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=0dbf6b6f-d39a-3797-a96c-940cbc51e9f8
2015-08-22 10:50:59.911  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2015-08-22 10:50:59.953  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration$ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration$ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$92b553c0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-08-22 10:51:00.818  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2015-08-22 10:51:01.576  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2015-08-22 10:51:01.579  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
2015-08-22 10:51:01.781  INFO 6628 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2015-08-22 10:51:01.782  INFO 6628 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4108 ms
2015-08-22 10:51:02.581  INFO 6628 --- [ost-startStop-1] b.a.s.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration : 

Using default security password: (left out here)

2015-08-22 10:51:02.655  INFO 6628 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/css/**'], []
2015-08-22 10:51:02.655  INFO 6628 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/js/**'], []
2015-08-22 10:51:02.657  INFO 6628 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/images/**'], []
2015-08-22 10:51:02.657  INFO 6628 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico'], []
2015-08-22 10:51:02.657  INFO 6628 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/error'], []
2015-08-22 10:51:02.737  INFO 6628 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@53e98fc, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@ed4e70e, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@49fcf6e3, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@6b376889, util.SecurityConfig$1@6fe7b32f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@6412fdf0, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@201fb3f3, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@11c0e0eb, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@5db14b9b, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@41cfdd62, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@21ce140, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@33b1cdbf]
2015-08-22 10:51:02.762  INFO 6628 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/**']]], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@359dd4a1, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@6e589ba9, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@71089e08, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@5b960164, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@7d8c46db, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5ad29d6, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@30e00fb5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@3b717854, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@713345c8, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@7fd28995, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@25c7da85]
2015-08-22 10:51:02.889  INFO 6628 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2015-08-22 10:51:02.890  INFO 6628 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2015-08-22 10:51:02.891  INFO 6628 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2015-08-22 10:51:03.167  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2015-08-22 10:51:03.168  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[text/html],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2015-08-22 10:51:03.215  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-08-22 10:51:03.284  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4d252d58: startup date [Sat Aug 22 10:50:57 CEST 2015]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@58be3622
2015-08-22 10:51:04.145  WARN 6628 --- [lication.main()] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2015-08-22 10:51:04.145  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2015-08-22 10:51:04.153  WARN 6628 --- [lication.main()] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2015-08-22 10:51:04.154  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2015-08-22 10:51:04.183  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2015-08-22 10:51:04.194  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'configurationPropertiesRebinder' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2015-08-22 10:51:04.196  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'refreshScope' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2015-08-22 10:51:04.197  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'environmentManager' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2015-08-22 10:51:04.201  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'environmentManager': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager]
2015-08-22 10:51:04.223  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'refreshScope': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh:name=refreshScope,type=RefreshScope]
2015-08-22 10:51:04.233  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinder': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties:name=configurationPropertiesRebinder,context=4d252d58,type=ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder]
2015-08-22 10:51:04.370  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2015-08-22 10:51:04.372  INFO 6628 --- [lication.main()] util.EditorApplication                   : Started EditorApplication in 10.655 seconds (JVM running for 32.345)
```

Comment: Try running mvn dependency:tree and post the output. The jar might arrive from some other dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check (and update question with) output of bootRun target? 
Before application is started,before first log line that comes from application, it shows the actual classpath used- with every jar file.
For me it is very long line (thousand of characters sometimes) starting with java  -cp .

Your depndency:tree looks fine, so most likely clean will make application use updated dependencies.

Looking at output of bootRun task, your issue is now resolved. Banner shows

> :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.4.RELEASE)

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud has its own dependencies which override the explicit ones. To see the versioning mapping of Spring Cloud with Spring boot, check out this resource:

http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/